# this в анонимную функцию

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть некий обьект

```
function Some(){
  this.first_object = new FirstObject();
  this.second_object = new SecondObject();

  this.init = function(){
    this.first_object.on("some_bind",function(){
      /*как получить доступ к this.second_object */
    });      
  }
}
```

Как получить доступ к объекту родителю из анонимной функции?

Answer (score 5):

Сохраните this в переменной, объявленной в области видимости перед созданием анонимный функции. таким образом вы создадите замыкание и получите доступ ко всему объекту.

```
   this.init = function(){
    var thisObj=this;
    this.first_object.on("some_bind",function(){
      thisObj.second_object...
    });
```

Comment: спасибо. Работает...

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev первый вариант короче будет, а так для каждого bind нужно определять именованную функцию....

Comment: @СергейДеревянко Именованную функцию объявлять не нужно. `bind` неплохо применяется и к анонимным функциям (что я и проделал в своем ответе). Как бы то ни было, всегда есть больше одного способа решить задачу ;)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev,  стрелочные-функции то что надо. Я и не знал о них...

Answer (score 3):

Используйте метод [`Function.protype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), определенный в стандарте ES5:

```
this.first_object.on("some_bind", (function(){
    // Здесь this имеет то же значение, что и в более высокой области
    // видимости.
}).bind(this));
```

**Замечание:**

Старые браузеры (IE < 9) не поддерживают `Function.prototype.bind`. Для них можно использовать один из существующих полифилов, например вот [этот](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы пишите код только для новых браузеров (совместимых с ES6/ES2015) или используете один из существующих транспайлеров (например, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)), то вы можете использовать вместо классических анонимных функций, т.н. [стрелочные-функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (arrow functions):

```
this.first_object.on("some_bind", () => {
    // Здесь this имеет то же значение, что и в более высокой области
    // видимости.
});
```

Стрелочные функции автоматически наследуют значение `this` из области видимости, в которой они определены.

Будьте внимательны, на сегодняшний день стрелочные функции поддерживаются [**не во всех браузерах**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). Поэтому, если вы не используете транспайлер JS кода, стоит дважды подумать перед их использованием в клиентских JavaScript приложениях!